# shopping cart is empty when I programmically create order

Tags: 7, commerce

I create a order with below code

```
      global $user;
     $product_id = 860;
     $price=intval($form_state['values']['field_suggest_your_price']['und'][0]['value']);
     dsm($price);
     dsm($form_state['values']);
// Create the new order in checkout; you might also check first to
// see if your user already has an order to use instead of a new one.
       $order = commerce_order_new($user->uid, 'checkout_checkout');

// Save the order to get its ID.
        commerce_order_save($order);

// Load whatever product represents the item the customer will be
// paying for and create a line item for it.
        $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
        $product->commerce_price["und"][0]["amount"]=$price;

        $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);
//// Save the line item to get its ID.
        commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
//// Add the line item to the order using fago's rockin' wrapper.
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
//// Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
commerce_order_save($order);
dsm($order);

//// Redirect to the order's checkout form. Obviously, if this were a
//// form submit handler, you'd just set $form_state['redirect'].
drupal_goto('checkout/' . $order->order_id);
```

but in `checkout/orderid`  shopping cart is empty, any body know where is my fault?
**appreciate any urgency help**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example on how to programmatically create an order and add a product to it, then redirect to checkout.

```
/**
 * Create new commerce_order with product
 * based on $_GET['pid'] from URL
 */
function MODULE_commerce_order_new(){

  global $user;

  // Sanitize just in case
  $product_id = filter_xss($_GET['pid']);

  // Load product
  $product = commerce_product_load((int)$product_id);

  if((empty($product->product_id)) || (!$product->status)){
    drupal_set_message(t('Invalid product id'));
    drupal_goto(); // frontpage
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Attempt to load existing order for user from session
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load();
  if(!$order){
    $order = commerce_cart_order_new($user->uid);
  }

  // Save new order to get order id
  if(empty($order->order_id)){
    $order->revision = FALSE;
    commerce_order_save($order);
  }
  $order_id = $order->order_id;

  // Wrapper for easy field access and adding line items, order passed by reference
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  // Create new line item based on selected product
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);
  // Save new line item to get line item id
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
  // Add line item to order wrapper
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

  // Save order with new order number and line item added
  $order->revision = FALSE;
  $order_wrapper->save();

  if(!empty($order->order_id)){
    drupal_set_message(t('Thank you, your %product is ready for checkout.',
                         array('%product' => $product->title)));
    drupal_goto('checkout/'.$order->order_id);
  }else{
    drupal_set_message(t('Sorry, there was a problem building your order. Please try again later.'), 'error');
    drupal_goto(); // frontpage
  }

}
```

Comment: I dsm the order and it is ok, the probelm is shopping cart content is empty , and can u tell me what is difference between your example and my code ( exclude your messages)

Comment: @zhilevan it may just be you need to use `commerce_cart_order_new` instead of `commerce_order_new` Also your setting the product price is a little odd, that should probably be done on the line item instead.

Comment: thanks for you explain, I want to change price of product , you tell it is better line item? can you tell me how?

Comment: I implement your method but yet the shop cart content is empty and not show any thing. ( I update the question and add a picture form result of your code ). can you tell me where is the problem and how can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example how to create commerce order programatically (it works with drush as well, e.g. `drush -vd -u "$1" scr order_code-7.php`).
Please note that `commerce_payment_example` module is required.

```
<?php

  if (!function_exists('drush_print')) {
    function drush_print ($text) {
      print $text . "\n";
    }
  }

  $is_cli = php_sapi_name() === 'cli';

  global $user;

  // Add the product to the cart
  $product_id = 5;
  $quantity = 1;

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Creating new order for ' . $quantity . ' item(s) of product ' . $product_id . '...');
  }

  // Create the new order in checkout; you might also check first to
  // see if your user already has an order to use instead of a new one.
  $order = commerce_order_new($user->uid, 'checkout_checkout');

  // Save the order to get its ID.
  commerce_order_save($order);

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Order created. Commerce order id is now ' . $order->order_id);
    drush_print('Searching product ' . $product_id . ' in a Commerce system...');
  }

  // Load whatever product represents the item the customer will be
  // paying for and create a line item for it.
  $product = commerce_product_load((int)$product_id);

  if((empty($product->product_id)) || (!$product->status)){
    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print('  Cannot match given product id with a Commerce product id.');
    }

    drupal_set_message(t('Invalid product id'));
    drupal_goto(); // frontpage
    return FALSE;
  }

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('  Found a Commerce product ' . $product->product_id . '.');
  }

  // Create new line item based on selected product
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('  Added product to the cart.');
  }

  // Save the line item to get its ID.
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

  // Add the line item to the order using fago's rockin' wrapper.
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Saving order...');
  }

  // Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
  commerce_order_save($order);

  // Redirect to the order's checkout form. Obviously, if this were a
  // form submit handler, you'd just set $form_state['redirect'].

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Checking out the order...');
  }

  commerce_checkout_complete($order);

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Marking order as fully paid...');
  }

  $payment_method = commerce_payment_method_instance_load('commerce_payment_example|commerce_payment_commerce_payment_example');

  if (!$payment_method) {
    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  No example payment method found, we can't mark order as fully paid. Please enable commerce_payment_example module to use this feature.");
    }
  }
  else {
    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  Creating example transaction...");
    }

    // Creating new transaction via commerce_payment_example module.
    $charge      = $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0];

    $transaction = commerce_payment_transaction_new('commerce_payment_example', $order->order_id);
    $transaction->instance_id = $payment_method['instance_id'];
    $transaction->amount = $charge['amount'];
    $transaction->currency_code = $charge['currency_code'];
    $transaction->status = COMMERCE_PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    $transaction->message = 'Name: @name';
    $transaction->message_variables = array('@name' => 'Example payment');

    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  Notifying Commerce about new transaction...");
    }

    commerce_payment_transaction_save($transaction);

    commerce_payment_commerce_payment_transaction_insert($transaction);
  }

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print("Marking order as completed...");
  }

  commerce_order_status_update($order, 'completed');

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print("\nDone.");
  }
```